# PHP Unset Array Object in foreach Loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, loops, foreach

I'm trying to `unset` stdClass object inside `foreach` loop. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($summaryResult)) {
        foreach($summaryResult as $rows) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $rows->st_date;?></td>
                <td>
                  <?php 
                      if(($rows->st_time_09 == '')&&($rows->st_time_11 == '')&&($rows->st_time_13 == '')){echo $rows->st_time_07;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_time_07 == '')&&($rows->st_time_11 == '')&&($rows->st_time_13 == '')){echo $rows->st_time_09;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_time_07 == '')&&($rows->st_time_09 == '')&&($rows->st_time_13 == '')){echo $rows->st_time_11;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_time_07 == '')&&($rows->st_time_09 == '')&&($rows->st_time_11 == '')){echo $rows->st_time_13;}
                      else{}
                    ?>                  
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php 
                      if(($rows->st_chlorine_09 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine_11 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine_13 == '')){echo $rows->st_chlorine_07;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_chlorine_07 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine_11 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine_13 == '')){echo $rows->st_chlorine_09;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_chlorine_07 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine_09 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine_13 == '')){echo $rows->st_chlorine_11;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_chlorine_07 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine_09 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine_11 == '')){echo $rows->st_chlorine_13;}
                      else{}
                    ?>  
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php 
                      if(($rows->st_time_15 == '')&&($rows->st_time_17 == '')&&($rows->st_time_19 == '')){echo $rows->st_time_21;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_time_21 == '')&&($rows->st_time_17 == '')&&($rows->st_time_19 == '')){echo $rows->st_time_15;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_time_21 == '')&&($rows->st_time_15 == '')&&($rows->st_time_19 == '')){echo $rows->st_time_17;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_time_21 == '')&&($rows->st_time_15 == '')&&($rows->st_time_17 == '')){echo $rows->st_time_19;}
                      else{}
                    ?>  
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php 
                      if(($rows->st_chlorine_21 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine_17 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine_19 == '')){echo $rows->st_chlorine_15;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_chlorine_21 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine_15 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine_19 == '')){echo $rows->st_chlorine_17;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_chlorine_21 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine_15 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine_17 == '')){echo $rows->st_chlorine_19;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_chlorine_15 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine_17 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine_19 == '')){echo $rows->st_chlorine_21;}
                      else{}
                  ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php 
                      if(($rows->st_time_23 == '')&&($rows->st_time_01 == '')&&($rows->st_time_03 == '')){echo $rows->st_time_05;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_time_05 == '')&&($rows->st_time_01 == '')&&($rows->st_time_03 == '')){echo $rows->st_time_23;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_time_05 == '')&&($rows->st_time_23 == '')&&($rows->st_time_03 == '')){echo $rows->st_time_01;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_time_05 == '')&&($rows->st_time_23 == '')&&($rows->st_time_01 == '')){echo $rows->st_time_03;}
                      else{}
                  ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php 
                      if(($rows->st_chlorine05 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine01 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine03 == '')){echo $rows->st_chlorine23;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_chlorine05 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine23 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine03 == '')){echo $rows->st_chlorine01;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_chlorine05 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine23 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine01 == '')){echo $rows->st_chlorine03;}
                      elseif(($rows->st_chlorine23 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine01 == '')&&($rows->st_chlorine03 == '')){echo $rows->st_chlorine05;}
                      else{}
                  ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php 
        } 


        // unset($summaryResult);  <== why this unset doesn't work ?
    } else { ?>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    } ?>
```

Above code is display the result like the following screenshot:

[image]

I want the data wrapping to 4 lines (check below screenshot) by `unset` every object which already printed. I've put `unset($summaryResult)` at the end 'foreach' loop but it doesn't work.

[image]

Any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: you unset is not inside the foreach

Comment: if unset inside the foreach, it will be stop after run one set of array. From what I'm understand, @metaphor try not to print a blank cell

Comment: You cannot just "unset" something here. Your whole structure of this file needs to be rebuilded for you to get desired table data display.

Comment: @weirdo _try no to print a blank cell_ how to do it ? i've tried using `array_diff` and `array_filter`. Btw, those fields are `String`. Is it possible to filter out the *empty strings only* according to above data ?

Comment: work on it.. but it hard because your data could be randomly inside your array.

Comment: @metaphor, can you give `print_r` value for `$summaryResult`

Comment: @weirdo here is the result: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/2mqRPHeQ)

Comment: @metaphor long array :). but hope you can review below concept.

Answer (score 0):

If I correct understand, you want do modify (unset) array inside of foreach loop ? Try to add & before value

Please try to change
   from

```
    foreach($summaryResult as $rows)
```

to

```
    foreach($summaryResult as &$rows)
```

For more info please follow link - http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop
>   precede $value with &

Comment: i can simply say i just want to reorder the data and not print the blank fields

Answer (score 0):

Assume your array like this;

```
$arr = array (
        array(  "time" => "30/06/2016", 
                "time1" => 11,
                "shift1" => 1,
                "time2"  => "",
                "shift2" => "",
                "time3"  => "",
                "shift3" => "",
                "time4"  => 6,
                "shift4" => 2
             ),
        array(  "time" => "30/06/2016", 
                "time1" => "",
                "shift1" => "",
                "time2"  => 2,
                "shift2" => 1,
                "time3"  => 3,
                "shift3" => 1,
                "time4"  => "",
                "shift4" => ""
             ),
        array(  "time" => "30/06/2016", 
                "time1" => "",
                "shift1" => "",
                "time2"  => 12,
                "shift2" => 1,
                "time3"  => "",
                "shift3" => "",
                "time4"  => 5,
                "shift4" => 3
             ),
        array(  "time" => "30/06/2016", 
                "time1" => 12,
                "shift1" => 0.9,
                "time2"  => "",
                "shift2" => "",
                "time3"  => 3,
                "shift3" => 1,
                "time4"  => "",
                "shift4" => ""
             )

    );
```

Vertical reading of array and grab only array with value;

```
foreach ($arr as $sub_arr)
{
    if ($sub_arr["time1"]) $new_arr["time1"][] = $sub_arr["time1"];
    if ($sub_arr["shift1"]) $new_arr["shift1"][] = $sub_arr["shift1"];

    if ($sub_arr["time2"]) $new_arr["time2"][] = $sub_arr["time2"];
    if ($sub_arr["shift2"]) $new_arr["shift2"][] = $sub_arr["shift2"];

    if ($sub_arr["time3"]) $new_arr["time3"][] = $sub_arr["time3"];
    if ($sub_arr["shift3"]) $new_arr["shift3"][] = $sub_arr["shift3"];

    if ($sub_arr["time4"]) $new_arr["time4"][] = $sub_arr["time4"];
    if ($sub_arr["shift4"]) $new_arr["shift4"][] = $sub_arr["shift4"];
}
```

reconstruct array to meet your purpose. Assume your array size after vertical reading will be same.

```
$count = count($new_arr["time1"]); // assume same size base on your data
for ($i=0; $i<$count;++$i)
{
    $mergArr[] = array(     "time1" => $new_arr["time1"][$i],
                            "shift1" => $new_arr["shift1"][$i],
                            "time2"  => $new_arr["time2"][$i],
                            "shift2" => $new_arr["shift2"][$i],
                            "time3"  => $new_arr["time3"][$i],
                            "shift3" => $new_arr["shift3"][$i],
                            "time4"  => $new_arr["time4"][$i],
                            "shift4" => $new_arr["shift4"][$i]
                         );
}
```

And lastly, replace your `foreach($summaryResult as $rows)` with `foreach($mergArr as $rows)` to create your table.

Maybe somebody can simplified the process and repair this answer for you.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge arrays together beforehand using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php), [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$result = array_reduce($summaryResult, function ($carry, $item) {
    $carry[$item['st_date']] = isset($carry[$item['st_date']]) 
        ? array_merge($carry[$item['st_date']], array_filter($item, 'strval'))
        : $item;

    return $carry;
}, []);
```

Also, when you `echo` data there is a pattern, I would suggest creating a function for that, so there's no code duplication.